# How to quote the fields of every row with awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have txt file like below

```
line1 record1 epm1 FY21 3
line2 record2 epm2 FY21 4 
line3 record3 epm3 FY21 7.23
line4 record4 epm4 FY21 90
```

I want to get output as below using awk or sed if possible

```
"line1" "record1" "epm1" "FY21" 3
"line2" "record2" "epm2" "FY21" 4 
"line3" "record3" "epm3" "FY21" 7.23
"line4" "record4" "epm4" "FY21" 90
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `sed` command:

```sh
sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]][^[:blank:]]*)/"\1"/g' file
```

Here:

- `[^[:blank:]]`: Matches a non-whitespace
- `[[:alpha:]]`: Matched an alphabetic character

```
"line1" "record1" "epm1" "FY21" 3
"line2" "record2" "epm2" "FY21" 4
"line3" "record3" "epm3" "FY21" 7.23
"line4" "record4" "epm4" "FY21" 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sprintf` to add quotes with `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF-1; i++) $i=sprintf("\"%s\"", $i)}1' file

# you can also use the form i<NF; to stop before the last field
```

Or string concatenation with escaped quotes:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF-1; i++) $i="\"" $i "\""}1' file
```

Or this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*$//g; s/([^[:blank:]]*)([[:blank:]])/"\1"\2/g' file

# the first s/[[:blank:]]*$//g; is to remove trailing spaces
```

If you might have multiple spaces between fields:

```
sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]*$//g; s/([^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*)([[:blank:]])/"\1"\2/g' file
```

Or this `perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's/(\S+)(\h+)(?=\S)/"\1"\2/g' file
# this works with tabs or spaces and variable number of spaces
# between records
```

All print:

```
"line1" "record1" "epm1" "FY21" 3
"line2" "record2" "epm2" "FY21" 4
"line3" "record3" "epm3" "FY21" 7.23
"line4" "record4" "epm4" "FY21" 90
```

Comment: `i<=NF-1` == `i<NF`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b[a-z]\S*/"&"/ig' file
```

Replace globally throughout each line, a string beginning with an alphabetic character, followed by zero or more other non-white spaced characters by - the match surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane '@F[0..3] = map { qq{"$_"} } @F[0..3]; print "@F";' in.txt > out.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

`@F[0..3] = map { ... } @F[0..3];` : Modify elements of @F with indexes 0 through 3 in-place, using whatever `map` does. `map` aliases the elements of the input list to `$_` variable.
`qq{"$_"}` returns the double-quoted `$_`. `qq{...}` is the same as `"..."` and used for convenience so that the actual double quotes inside it do not have to be escaped.
`"@F"` : elements of the array `@F` joined on spaces.

**NOTE:**
If you have tab-delimited input, use this Perl one-liner instead:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '@F[0..3] = map { qq{"$_"} } @F[0..3]; print join "\t", @F;' in.txt > out.txt
```

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Thank you all i was able to get do done with sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]*[[:alpha:]][^[:blank:]]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, without using loop with `match` option of `awk` in shown samples.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,/.* /){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +$/,"",val)
  gsub(/ /,s1 "&" s1,val)
  print s1 val s1,$NF
  val=""
}
' Input_file
```